# Memory leak using AdMediator with pubCenter and AdMob

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, admob

I'm using the latest version of **AdMediator** in my **Silverlight Windows Phone 8.0** application.

I'm using it with **Google AdMob** and **Microsoft pubCenter**.

I've noticed that, when I navigate to other pages, **AdMediatorControl doesn't release its memory**, in fact after 10~15 navigations (depending on how many ads I put on the pages) the application crashes with an **OutOfMemoryException**.

If I **remove the AdMediatorControl** from the XAML this doesn't happen and **the memory is correctly released** (I can see it in Windows Phone Developer Power Tools).

I tried to **set my AdMediatorControl instance to null** on the event OnNavigatedFrom but this **doesn't change anything**.

I can't publish my app because of this. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
I just had to use the same instance for the whole app.

Here's how I solved the issue:

I've removed AdMediator and instantiated the banners manually using C#.
So, I've created a single instance of AdView and AdRequest (public static) in the class App which I initialize in the event Application_Launching.

Then, in every page where I needed a banner, in the event OnNavigatedTo I set the AdView of App class as a children of the page Grid (ContentGrid) and launch the LoadAd method on the AdRequest instance of the App class.

Then, in the event OnNavigatedFrom, I remove the AdView from the Children of the Grid.

Done! No more memory leak! :D